# Improve performance to find an array of ids from array of hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Consider a array of hashes

```
a=[{'id'=>'1','imageUrl'=>'abc'},{'id'=>'2','imageUrl'=>'efg'},{'id'=>'3','imageUrl'=>'hij'}]
```

Consider an array of characters/numbers/ids

```
b=['1','2','5']
```

I would like to match ids of b with a. With all matches, I would like to replace the value of b with the corresponding hash.

In the above example, the values '1' and '2' are common between a and b, so I replace '1' and '2' in b with the corresponding hash values of a.

So the resultant b becomes

```
b=[[{"id"=>"1", "imageUrl"=>"abc"}], [{"id"=>"2", "imageUrl"=>"efg"}], []]
```

I wrote the following code:

```
b.each_with_index{|r,index|
puts index
k=a.select {|z| z["id"]==r }
b[index]=k
}
```

Is there a better solution? A more sleek one. I am new to ruby.

Comment: What's the rush in selecting an answer? An least one reader is still preparing an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will improve speed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'pp'
require 'benchmark'

a = []
5000.times {|c| a << {"id" => "#{c}", "imageUrl" => "test#{c}"}}
b1 = (1..2500).to_a.shuffle.map(&:to_s) 
b2 = b1.dup()

puts "method1"
puts Benchmark.measure { b1.map! {|id| a.select {|h| h['id'] == id }} }

puts "method2"
result = Benchmark.measure do
    ah = Hash.new([])
    a.each{|x| ah[x["id"]] = x}
    b2.map!{|be| ah[be]}
end
puts result
```

Results:

```
method1
  2.820000   0.010000   2.830000 (  2.827695)
method2
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.002607)
```

Updated benchmark - it uses **250000** elements in b instead of **2500** (method 1 commented out to protect the innocent - it's too slow and I got bored waiting for it):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'pp'
require 'benchmark'

a = []
5000.times {|c| a << {"id" => "#{c}", "imageUrl" => "test#{c}"}}
b1 = (1..250000).to_a.collect{|x| x%2500}.shuffle.map(&:to_s)
b2 = b1.dup()
b3 = b1.dup()

# puts "method1"
# puts Benchmark.measure { b1.map! {|id| a.select {|h| h['id'] == id }} }

puts "method2"
result = Benchmark.measure do
    ah = Hash.new([])
    a.each{|x| ah[x["id"]] = x}
    b2.map!{|be| ah[be]}
end
puts result

puts "method3"
result = Benchmark.measure do
    h = a.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g['id']=>g) }
    b3.map! { |s| h.key?(s) ? [h[s]] : [] }
end
puts result
```

And the results are:

```
method2
  0.050000   0.000000   0.050000 (  0.045294)
method3
  0.100000   0.010000   0.110000 (  0.109646)
```

Comment: Mircea, could you add my solution to the benchmark, and also compare when `b` is substantially larger than `a`?

Comment: My solution appears to be the same as yours, so don't bother including mine. Maybe include my  solution that uses `values_at` for a comparison--I don't think it will make much difference however. Ha! I just now noticed your benchmark results.

Comment: updated. yours is a bit slower, but still pretty fast compared to the "naive" solution :) hah

Comment: The second method is quite fast.

Comment: One question though.

a.each{|x| ah[x["id"]] = x}

This creates a hash and assigns id to entire hash.

Is it possible to assign the id, to only certain key value pairs?

For example:
Instead of this :
{"1"=>{"id"=>"1", "imageUrl"=>"abc"}

Can i do 

{"1"=>{"imageUrl"=>"abc"}

Assume that there are a lot more key/value pairs in the hash and I dont need all of them

Comment: yes, you can select whatever you like from the hash (ie you don't need to put stuff that's not needed in there). reason this is superfast is because of the precomputing that happens upfront - it's a classical "you trade some space for speed"

Answer (score 4):

You can use the destructive version of [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), with [Enumerable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)

```
b.map! {|id| a.select {|h| h['id'] == id }}
# => [[{"id"=>"1", "imageUrl"=>"abc"}], [{"id"=>"2", "imageUrl"=>"efg"}], []]
```

Comment: How about this

k=a.select {|z| b.include?z['id'] }

Comment: It will not have an empty array, in case of no match, which you needed in the expected output.

Comment: this does not improve performance. or large arrays it will behave badly because of the select

Comment: any better solutions?

Comment: see below (precompute and after that transform once)

Comment: This solution is for the "sleek" part. Performance will be similar to OP's original solution. For very large Arrays, see Mircea's answer, which has some awesome benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

**[Edit:** after posting I noticed @Mircea had already posted the same solution. I'll leave mine for the mention of the `values_at` alternative.**]**

I assume the values of `:id` in `a` are unique.

First construct a look-up hash:

```
h = a.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g['id']=>g) }
  #=> {"1"=>{"id"=>"1", "imageUrl"=>"abc"},
  #    "2"=>{"id"=>"2", "imageUrl"=>"efg"},
  #    "3"=>{"id"=>"3", "imageUrl"=>"hij"}}
```

Then simply loop through `b`, constructing the desired array:

```
b.map { |s| h.key?(s) ? [h[s]] : [] }
  #=> [[{"id"=>"1", "imageUrl"=>"abc"}],
  #    [{"id"=>"2", "imageUrl"=>"efg"}],
  #    []]
```

Alternatively,

```
arr = h.values_at(*b)
 #=> [{"id"=>"1", "imageUrl"=>"abc"},
 #    {"id"=>"2", "imageUrl"=>"efg"},
 #    nil]
```

Then:

```
arr.map { |e| e.nil? ? [] : [e] }
  #=> [[{"id"=>"1", "imageUrl"=>"abc"}],
  #    [{"id"=>"2", "imageUrl"=>"efg"}],
  #    []]
```

You might instead consider using `arr` for subsequent calculations, since all the arrays in your desired solution contain at most one element.

The use of a lookup hash is especially efficient when `b` is large relative to `a`.

Comment: cannot get the values_at to work for very large sizes of the b array

Comment: @Mircea, that's odd. I'll have a look in the morning.

Comment: may be doing something wrong, but I get: arr = h.values_at(*b1)
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/irb/workspace.rb:86
Maybe IRB bug!